# xampp Windows HTTP Error 404.0

Tags: mysql, windows, xampp

I am running xampp on windows 8.

So I start my xampp and start Apache and MySQL. Everything is running as you can see here

[image]

Than when I click `MySQL Admin` it goes to `localhost/phpmyadmin` but it returns me an 404 error -

[image]

Than I have to type manualy `localhost:8080/phpmyadmin` and visit, but it also return me a 404 error -

[image]

What I should to fix this problem !

Anyone have an idea of this problem to fix !

Comment: You don't need Tomcat to run phpmyadmin. Close Tomcat and try again. Also the correct url is http://localhost/phpmyadmin/

Comment: @ManosPasgiannis have tried your suggestion but still it is the same result

Comment: Are you sure phpmyadmin is installed? I don't know if xampp installs it by default

Comment: @ManosPasgiannis as far as I know it does install the phpmyadmin while installing the xampp

Answer (score 6):

I have solved this problem. At 1st click on configure tab (top most at right side), then click on "Service & Port Setting", then edit main port and ssl port as you configured.

Shaiket Hasnien

Comment: Long time ago but to useful comment @Shaiket Hasnien.  For me, the ports shown under XAMPP control panel were 81, 443 but in the "Service & Port Settings" > Apache tab it read 80, 443.  Changing to 81, 443 and saving did the trick and now the URL is http://localhost:81/dashboard/ and http://localhost:81/phpmyadmin/.